# TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable while creating custom thread pool

Tags: python, multithreading, typeerror, python-3.7

I want to create a custom thread pool for having more control over the code for future needs. So far I haven't been able to write something functional. I want the threads to work separately from the main interpreter process. I don't need multi-core advantage. Threads(Worker) should listen for a change in queue size and run execute on the passed job. I cannot make this code work. Does anybody see any solution to make this work?

```
import queue
from threading import Thread
import time
import random

class Worker(Thread):
#----------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self,queue,x):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.run = True
        self.queue = queue
        self.x = x
#----------------------------------------------------------
    def run(self):
        while self.run:
            while not self.queue.empty():
                job = self.queue.get()
                print("Starting", job, self.x)
                job.execute()
                time.sleep(0.1)
                self.queue.task_done()
            time.sleep(0.1)

class TestJob:
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

    def execute(self):
        print(f"Num {self.x}")

class DownloadManager:
    def __init__(self,numOfThread):
        self.jobQueue = queue.Queue()
        self.numOfThread = numOfThread
        self.threadList = [Worker(self.jobQueue, x) for x in range(0, self.numOfThread)]
        [x.start() for x in self.threadList]
        print("End of init")

    def addJob(self,job):
        self.jobQueue.put(job)

dm = DownloadManager(2)

for x in range(0,10):
    job = TestJob(x)
    dm.addJob(job)

print("After adding all jobs")
input("Waiting for enter")
print("Done")
```

**CONSOLE OUTPUT**

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
End of init
Traceback (most recent call last):
After adding all jobs
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Waiting for enterException in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable



Done
```

**My Python version is 3.7.2.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Worker` class has 2 attributes for `run`.

```py
class Worker(Thread):
#----------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self,queue,x):
        ...
        self.run = True       
        ...
#----------------------------------------------------------
    def run(self):            
        while self.run:
            ...
```

One is a boolean (`self.run = True`) and one is a function (`def run(self):`).

[You can't have both a method and an attribute with the same name.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12949064/2745495)

Based on the error message, `self.run()` is being called, so `run` is expected be a function. Try changing the property `self.run` to some other name (ex. `self.is_running`).