# 'bool' object is not callable when accessing multiprocessing.reduction?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am writing a code to parallelize a task using Python 3.x multiprocessing library.

I have two classes, (Content of which is too large to be pasted), and two functions like so:

```
def abc_1(objekt, raw):
    return raw + "changed"


def file_task(file_name):
    con_fig = Some_Config()
    obj_ect = Some_other_class(con_fig)
    pool = Pool(4)
    with open(file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
        res = pool.map(partial(abc_1, con_fig), fh, 4)
    return res
```

When I run above code I get this error:

```
cls = <class 'multiprocessing.reduction.ForkingPickler'>
obj = (0, 0, <function mapstar at 0x10abec9d8>, ((functools.partial(<function abc_1 at 0x10ad98620>, <project.some_file.... 'Indeed, Republican lawyers identified only 300 cases of electoral fraud in the United States in a decade.\n')),), {})
protocol = None

@classmethod
def dumps(cls, obj, protocol=None):
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)

    TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

However, If I change my two functions like so, where I don't need to send object of a class to my function abc_1 which I want parallelized, it works fine:

```
def abc_1(raw):
    return raw + "changed"


def file_task(file_name):
    con_fig = Some_Config()
    obj_ect = Some_other_class(con_fig)
    pool = Pool(4)
    with open(file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
        res = pool.map(abc_1, fh, 4)
    return res
```

I would think "partial" is the culprit but even this works:

```
def file_task(file_name):
    con_fig = Some_Config()
    obj_ect = Some_other_class(con_fig)
    pool = Pool(4)
    with open(file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
        res = pool.map(partial(abc_1), fh, 4)
    return res
```

Since, I haven't provided the content that I have in my classes, I understand his makes answering my question, hard.

I have gone through several such posts: [TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable while creating custom thread pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56408992/typeerror-bool-object-is-not-callable-while-creating-custom-thread-pool)

Nothing of this sort is happening in my code, not even in my classes.

Could my initializations in my class be leading to the error I am getting ? What else could be causing this ? What are some things to keep in mind which passing class instance to a function during multiprocessing ?

It will really help if someone can point me in right direction.

Comment: Is it possible that there is something in `con_fig` that can't be pickled?  That would explain the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: There was. I had a Tuple in my con_fig, but back then I was getting the standard pickling error from Python "Can't Pickle object". I changed the data type and that is when I started seeing this behavior. Current data types are only a List and a Dictionary.

Comment: When I try setting con_fig to the string `"configuration"`, the code works just fine.  So I'm really suspicious of whatever's in it.

Comment: That URL gives me a 404.

Comment: Apologies: https://pastebin.pl/view/130b31ca

Comment: Or this is valid for one day: https://pastebin.pl/view/a28fab2e