# Python accessing similarly named class and instance attributes

Tags: python, class, instance

I have a class with class and instance attributes with the same name. Is there a way to return their respected value based on the context they are accessed?

Example:

```
class A:
    b = 'test'
    @property
    def b(self):
        return 'not test'
```

Desired Results:

```
>>> A().b
'not test'
>>> A.b
'test'
```

Actual Results:

```
>>> A().b
'not test'
>>> A.b
<property object at 0x03ADC640>
```

Comment: you named your `property` that, which replaced your previous assignment to `b`. You *could* use an actual instance attribute

Comment: Is there a reason not to use different names for different attributes?

Comment: My current implementation uses different names (`b` for the instance variable and `b_` for the class variable).

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you want that, but this would work:

```
class ClassWithB(type):
    @property
    def b(self):
        return 'test'


class A(metaclass=ClassWithB):
    @property
    def b(self):
        return 'not test'
```

It behaves like this:

```
>>> A.b
'test'
>>> A().b
'not test'
```

You could also use e.g. a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html):

```
class B:
    def __get__(self, obj, type_=None):
        if obj is None:
            return 'test'
        else:
            return 'not test'

class A:
    b = B()
```

Answer (score 0):

No - the method shadows the instance - see this for more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/12949375/13085236